# Making everything align in print preview VB

Tags: vb.net, print-preview

Im trying to make everything align but im not fully sure how...
This is by far what i made but the items name, price and the others are not in an align form...
Is there any way to make them align?
heres my code...

```
  Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim printFont As New Font("Courier New", 10)
    'Dim headingFont As New Font("Courier New", 10)
    Dim sngLineHeight As Single = printFont.GetHeight + 2
    Dim sngXLocation As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
    Dim sngYLocation As Single = e.MarginBounds.Top
    Dim intItemCount As Integer
    e.Graphics.DrawString("                   XXXX  Restaurant                   ", printFont, Brushes.Black, sngXLocation, sngYLocation)
    sngYLocation += sngLineHeight
    e.Graphics.DrawString("                       RECEIPT                         ", printFont, Brushes.Black, sngXLocation, sngYLocation)
    sngYLocation += sngLineHeight
    e.Graphics.DrawString("========================================================", printFont, Brushes.Black, sngXLocation, sngYLocation)
    sngYLocation += sngLineHeight

    e.Graphics.DrawString(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm dddd, dd MMMM yyyy"), printFont, Brushes.Black, sngXLocation, sngYLocation)
    sngYLocation += sngLineHeight
    sngYLocation += sngLineHeight

    Dim ptOne As Point
    Dim ptTwo As Point
    ptOne.X = 10
    ptOne.Y = 10

    ptTwo.X = 10
    ptTwo.Y = 200
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, ptOne, ptTwo)
    intItemCount = frmSalesManagement.dgvSaleManagement.Rows.Count
    Dim strItemDesc As String
    Dim strItemDesc2 As String
    Dim strItemDesc3 As String
    Dim strItemDesc4 As String
    Dim strTableNo As String
    Dim strNoOfPerson As String


    strTableNo = frmSalesManagement.txtTableNo.Text
    strNoOfPerson = frmSalesManagement.txtNoOfPerson.Text
    If frmSalesManagement.lblMemberName.Text <> "" Then
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Member's Name     : " & frmSalesManagement.lblMemberName.Text.ToString, printFont, Brushes.Black, sngXLocation, sngYLocation)
        sngYLocation += sngLineHeight
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Member's Discount : 10%", printFont, Brushes.Black, sngXLocation, sngYLocation)
        sngYLocation += sngLineHeight
    End If

    e.Graphics.DrawString("Table No.: " & strTableNo, printFont, Brushes.Black, sngXLocation, sngYLocation)
    sngYLocation += sngLineHeight
    e.Graphics.DrawString("No of Person : " & strNoOfPerson, printFont, Brushes.Black, sngXLocation, sngYLocation)
    sngYLocation += sngLineHeight
    sngYLocation += sngLineHeight
    e.Graphics.DrawString("ItemName" & vbTab & "" & vbTab & "Price" & vbTab & "" & vbTab & "Quantity" & vbTab & "" & vbTab & "Subtotal", printFont, Brushes.Black, sngXLocation, sngYLocation)
    sngYLocation += sngLineHeight
    sngYLocation += sngLineHeight
    For i As Integer = 0 To intItemCount - 1



        strItemDesc = frmSalesManagement.dgvSaleManagement.Rows(i).Cells(0).FormattedValue.ToString() + "" & vbTab & "" & vbTab
        strItemDesc2 = frmSalesManagement.dgvSaleManagement.Rows(i).Cells(1).FormattedValue.ToString() + "" & vbTab & "" & vbTab
        strItemDesc3 = frmSalesManagement.dgvSaleManagement.Rows(i).Cells(2).FormattedValue.ToString() + "" & vbTab & "" & vbTab
        strItemDesc4 = frmSalesManagement.dgvSaleManagement.Rows(i).Cells(3).FormattedValue.ToString() + "" & vbTab & "" & vbTab


        e.Graphics.DrawString(strItemDesc & strItemDesc2 & strItemDesc3 & strItemDesc4, printFont, Brushes.Black, sngXLocation, sngYLocation)


        sngYLocation += sngLineHeight
    Next

    If lblMethodOfPayment.Text = "Cash" Then
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Payment Method : " & lblMethodOfPayment.Text.ToString, printFont, Brushes.Black, sngXLocation, sngYLocation)
        sngYLocation += sngLineHeight
        sngYLocation += sngLineHeight
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Discount    :  " & frmSalesManagement.txtDiscount.Text.ToString() & "%", printFont, Brushes.Black, sngXLocation, sngYLocation)
        sngYLocation += sngLineHeight

        e.Graphics.DrawString("Due Amount  :  RM" & lblDueAmount.Text.ToString, printFont, Brushes.Black, sngXLocation, sngYLocation)
        sngYLocation += sngLineHeight
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Amount Paid :  RM" & txtAmountPaid.Text.ToString, printFont, Brushes.Black, sngXLocation, sngYLocation)
        sngYLocation += sngLineHeight
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Change      :  RM" & lblChange.Text.ToString, printFont, Brushes.Black, sngXLocation, sngYLocation)
        sngYLocation += sngLineHeight
        sngYLocation += sngLineHeight
        e.Graphics.DrawString("======================= Thank You ======================", printFont, Brushes.Black, sngXLocation, sngYLocation)
        sngYLocation += sngLineHeight
        e.Graphics.DrawString("========================== End =========================", printFont, Brushes.Black, sngXLocation, sngYLocation)
        sngYLocation += sngLineHeight
    ElseIf lblMethodOfPayment.Text = "Visa Card" Or lblMethodOfPayment.Text = "Master Card" Then
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Payment Method : " & lblMethodOfPayment.Text.ToString, printFont, Brushes.Black, sngXLocation, sngYLocation)
        sngYLocation += sngLineHeight
        sngYLocation += sngLineHeight
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Discount    :  " & frmSalesManagement.txtDiscount.Text.ToString() & "%", printFont, Brushes.Black, sngXLocation, sngYLocation)
        sngYLocation += sngLineHeight

        e.Graphics.DrawString("Due Amount  :  RM" & lblDueAmount.Text.ToString, printFont, Brushes.Black, sngXLocation, sngYLocation)
        sngYLocation += sngLineHeight
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Amount Paid :  RM" & txtAmountPaid.Text.ToString, printFont, Brushes.Black, sngXLocation, sngYLocation)
        sngYLocation += sngLineHeight
        sngYLocation += sngLineHeight
        e.Graphics.DrawString("======================= Thank You ======================", printFont, Brushes.Black, sngXLocation, sngYLocation)
        sngYLocation += sngLineHeight
        e.Graphics.DrawString("========================== End =========================", printFont, Brushes.Black, sngXLocation, sngYLocation)
        sngYLocation += sngLineHeight
    End If
    sngYLocation += sngLineHeight


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

It will probably align okay in your text editor because it uses a font like Consolas or New Century.  A font where every letter has the same width.  And intentionally picked to get the statements in your code to line up.

But that won't work on a printer, you'll print with a variable pitched font.  Like the text in this answer, the letter i takes a lot less space than the letter W: iiiiii vs WWWWWW.

So don't put spaces in the DrawString() text, that's not going to align.  Instead use the overload of DrawString that takes a RectangleF and a StringFormat.  So you use, say, StringAlignment.Center and get the string perfectly centered in the rectangle.  Use the same rectangle width in the next line and the text will be perfectly centered with the previous line.  Using a fixed-pitch font for the printer will solve your problem as well, but nobody likes the way that looks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically like this ..

```
Dim x as Single = Convert.ToSingle(e.PageBounds.Width / 2 - e.Graphics.MeasureString("XXXX  Restaurant", PrintFont).Width / 2)

e.Graphics.DrawString("XXXX  Restaurant",PrintFont, Brushes.Black, x, 100)
```